# python arrays, huge memory consumption

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge file with the first row as a string and others rows represent integers. The number of columns is variable, dependent on a row.
A have one global list where I save my intermediate results. `arr_of_arr` is an list of lists of floats. The length of `arr_of_arr` is about 5000. Each element (again an array) of this array has a length from 100.000 to 10.000.000. The maximum length of the elements might vary, so I cannot extend each element in advance when I create arr_of_arr.

After I have proceeded the whole file,I add artificially  I compute the mean over the elements for each of the global array and plot.`max_size_arr` is a length of the longest element in an array ( I compete it when I iterate over the lines in file)

```
arr = [x+[0]*(max_size_arr - len(x)) for x in arr_of_arr]
```

I need to calculate the means across arrays element wise.
For example,
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,2,10]] would result in [5/3,9/3,19/3] (mean of the first elements across arrays, mean od second elements across arrays etc.)

```
arr = np.mean(np.array(arr),axis=0)
```

However, this result in a huge memory consumption (like 100GB according to the cluster information). What would be a good solution in sense of structure to reduce memory consumption? Would numpy arrays be lighter than the normal arrays in python?

Comment: you need to change the way you are accessing the elements, store the first element of each array in its own array e.g. [[1,4,0],[2,5,2] etc.. it sounds to me like your memory is trashing by accessing the elements out of order

Comment: Another solution would be the use of yielding, ([see the post about yielding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)).

Comment: `arr_of_arr` should be a list.  Making it an object type array just complicates matters.

Comment: What do you mean by `normal arrays`?  Python has lists.

Comment: @scrineym I do not access the elements out of order. I can use only 100GB in cluster and my code with the array_of_array exceeds that.

Comment: @hpaulj it is a list, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think that the huge memory consumption is because you want to have the whole array in memory at once.

Why don't you use slices combined with [numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast)?. Doing that you can simulate a batch processing of your data. You can give to a function the batch size (1000 or 10000 arrays), calculate the means and write the results into a dict or a file indicating slices and its own respectives means.

Comment: I need to calculate the mean column-wise, so, read firstly all rows (some rows I need to extend by additional columns because rows can have different number of columns) and then I calculate the mean. To calculate the mean of the first 1000 rows and then of the next 1000 rows is not appropriate for me.

Comment: But you can slice over [columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386675/extracting-specific-columns-in-numpy-array) too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Numba package? It reduces computation time and memory usage with standard numpy arrays.
http://numba.pydata.org

Answer (score 0):

If the lines vary widely in the number of values, I'd stick with a list of lists, at long as is practical.  `numpy` arrays are best when the data is 'row' lengths are the same.

To illustrate with a small example:

```
In [453]: list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8,9],[0],[1,2]]

In [454]: list_of_lists
Out[454]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0], [1, 2]]

In [455]: [len(x) for x in list_of_lists]
Out[455]: [3, 6, 1, 2]

In [456]: [sum(x) for x in list_of_lists]
Out[456]: [6, 39, 0, 3]

In [458]: [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in list_of_lists]
Out[458]: [2.0, 6.5, 0.0, 1.5]
```

With your array approach to taking the mean, I get different numbers - because of all the padding 0s.  Is that intentional?

```
In [460]: max_len=6

In [461]: arr=[x+[0]*(max_len-len(x)) for x in list_of_lists]

In [462]: arr
Out[462]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

mean along columns?

```
In [463]: np.mean(np.array(arr),axis=0)
Out[463]: array([ 1.5 ,  2.25,  2.25,  1.75,  2.  ,  2.25])
```

mean along rows

```
In [476]:     In [463]: np.mean(np.array(arr),axis=1)
Out[476]: array([ 1. ,  6.5,  0. ,  0.5])
```

list mean with max length:

```
In [477]: [sum(x)/float(max_len) for x in list_of_lists]
Out[477]: [1.0, 6.5, 0.0, 0.5]
```