# Why am I getting the following error: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (423, 2) instead. (in Python)

Tags: python, train-test-split

I am trying to calculate the AUC-ROC curve for a logistic regression function using the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
lr_model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)
lr_test_probs = lr_model.predict_proba(x_test)
lr_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, lr_test_probs)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (423, 2) instead.

I think this is because of y_test, which has the shape (423,2) as it has 423 rows and 2 columns, the first column being the index. I tried to get rid of the index by using to_numpy() like so:

```
y_test2=y_test.to_numpy()
y_train2=y_train.to_numpy()
x_test2=x_test.to_numpy()
x_train2=x_train.to_numpy()
```

but I still got the same error, even though when I call y_test2 it is simply an array with 0s and 1s and no index column.
I also tried to change x and y into arrays first using the to_numpy() function and then calculate the test and train data after, and I am still getting the same error.

Any advice on what to do?

edit: running print(y.head(5)) gives:
[print(y.head(5))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24lPE.png)

Comment: `to_numpy` doesn't change the shape of the data. You need to actually extract the column you want.  Does this answer your question? [Extracting specific columns in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386675/extracting-specific-columns-in-numpy-array)

Comment: what does `y` look like? do a `print(y.head(5))` for me and add that in the post

Comment: @PranavHosangadi when I try to use y_test[:,1] I get the error: ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Comment: @chitown88 I added the image to the post as a link!

Answer (score 0):

Set y to be a series with what ever your target column name is. You could also just select the last column (that is assuming that is the column you want though)

So something like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
y = y[['target_column_name']] # <--- insert the name of the column thats your target
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
lr_model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)
lr_test_probs = lr_model.predict_proba(x_test)
lr_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, lr_test_probs)
```